# Return statement within an AsyncCallback?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a Windows Phone 7 app where one portion of it takes in a URL and checks if the website is still live. The problem is I can't do a return statement inside of the HTTP request and as a result, websites that don't work won't show up as not working in the app.

```
        private string check(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
            new Uri(url));
            request.BeginGetResponse(r =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)r.AsyncState;
                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(r);

                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    return "\u2612"; //Error here
                }
            }, request);
        }
        catch
        {
            return "\u2612";
        }
        return "\u2611";
    }
```

When I try to compile this code, I get these errors:

> Error 1   Since 'System.AsyncCallback' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression
>
> Error 2   Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.AsyncCallback' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Is there any way around this or some other way to get that return statement to work?

Comment: You're calling synchronous methods, so you won't be able to return any value from the method.  You'll need to expose the logical result to the caller in another way, just like `BeginGetRequest` does.

Answer (score 1):

you can use callback result type like this :

```
  private void check(string url, Action<string> act)
  {
    try
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
        new Uri(url));
        request.BeginGetResponse(r =>
        {
            try
            {
                var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)r.AsyncState;
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(r);

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                act("\u2612");
            }
        }, request);
    }
    catch
    {
        act(\u2612");
    }
    act("\u2611");  //may be this call must comment!
}
```

in anonymous method if you return value it mean that anonymous method will return value not who method called it.

if you write

```
request.BeginGetResponse(r => {
    return "";
}
```

this mean you pass anonymous method to BeginGetResponse method that has no input parameter and return string parameter.

and BeginGetResponse dos not accept this type of method

**UPDATE**

and when you want to use :

```
check(s, (myReturnValue) => {
     //myReturnValue is result of method
     results.Add(myReturnValue);
     //Code in here guaranteed results is filled always...
});
//Code in here is not guaranteed  results is filled if you comment code that i suggested, because it fill in callback method and callback method will called in async method...
```

**IMPORTANT**

this method will execute async action it mean
results.Add(myReturnValue); is **not** execute exactly after calling check method, because it is async
in this way you can not explicitly have return value, and you can use callback method.

if you want execute without async and define explicitly return value for check method you can call GetResponse instead of BeginGetResponse.

Comment: How do I get the values I need from that though? My current way of getting the return values is this:

results.Add(check(s));

I'm not sure how to rewrite that to get the same intended results

Comment: It compiles fine now, but it seems to always return the value that you suggested to be commented out. But if I comment it out, the program crashes because it's missing return values. I tried calling just GetResponse but it says that System.Net.HttpWebRequest does not contain a definition for GetResponse

Comment: @Generalkidd oh i think GetResponse is not implement in windows-phone, i dont know winodows-phone has implement System.Threading.ManualResetEvent, but if implement it, you can use it for here

Comment: @Generalkidd please see new comment in my post

Comment: Ok, I'll see if there's a way I can try the manuresetevent. The check() calls are actually called within a foreach loop so code afterwards should still work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77365/discussion-between-emran-sadeghi-and-generalkidd).